# are there limits for spring SpEL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I need to know are there limits for spring SpEL in terms of syntax and capabilities. For example I need to run this expression:

```
Integer cnt=0;
if(obj.val1<10){return 1;}
else{
cnt=cnt+1;
}
```

and so on. Is there a way to run a simple sub-program like one expression?

Comment: `cnt=cnt++;` Are you sure about that? `cnt` will keep its **0** after that statement.

Comment: Sorry, I have already fixed it, it`s just an example. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

SpEL is not really intended to be a complete programming language. It's an expression language, like [the EL in JEE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html), intended to make simple things like logic in web pages, extensions, etc, easier.

You can do a lot in SpEL. It doesn't have direct support for looping, but you can do some of the same things with a [projection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-projection).

I've used it in a project and it's very powerful and quite fast.

Comment: I don't know why my answer was edited to say "in JavaScript" instead of "in JEE", but "in JEE" is correct, as indicated by the underlying link. JEE has an EL that is used in JSF for example. I don't know of any EL that's "in JavaScript".